# rails rspec - (2nd test) Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, controller

Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>

My tests has:

```
describe "Link POST #create" do

  context "with valid attributes" do
    it "creates a new link" do
      expect{
        post :create, link: FactoryGirl.create(:link, :group => @group)
      }.to change(Link,:count).by(1)
    end

    it "redirects to the new link" do
      post :create, link: FactoryGirl.create(:link, :group => @group)
      # response.should redirect_to @link # Link.unscoped.last
      response.should redirect_to Link.unscoped.last # render_template :show
    end
  end
```

The first test passes but the second fails.

My code is:

```
  def create
    @link = Link.new(params[:link])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Link was successfully created.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@link) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @link, :status => :created, :location => @link }
      else
        @selected_group = params[:group_id]
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @link.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I've tried redirect and render but can't get the 2nd test to pass.

Comment: Is `FactoryGirl.create(:link, :group => @group)` giving you an object or a hash of the object's attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should make it work:

```
describe "Link POST #create" do

  context "with valid attributes" do

    def do_post( format = 'html' )
      attributes = FactoryGirl.build(:link).attributes.merge( :group_id => @group.id )
      post :create, :link => attributes, :format => 'html'
    end

    it "creates a new link" do
      expect{
        do_post
      }.to change(Link,:count).by(1)
    end

    it "redirects to the new link" do
      do_post
      response.should redirect_to( assigns[:link] )
    end
  end
```

The first spec was working only because you were calling **FactoryGirl.create** so a record was being created out of the controller, but most likely the controller call wasn't working.